# comparing two variables returns false result

Tags: php, string

Why does this always return `true`:

```
$s = '334rr';
$i = (int)$s;

if ($i == $s) {
    echo true;
} else {
    echo false;
}
```

If I echo `$i` it gives the value of `334`, which is different from `$s` which is `334rr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

So: `($i == $s)` is the same as `($i == (int)$s)` for the values you've given.

Use `===` to avoid type-juggling.

Answer (score 2):

When compare string with integer using `==`, string will try to case into integer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$s = '334rr';
$i = intval($s);
if ($i == $s) {
 echo true;
 } else {
  echo false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing strings to an int is not recommended. You should use the `===` instead which will verify the same data type as well as the same value.

Answer (score 0):

PHP converts the $s string to an integer when comparing to another integer ($i).
It basically does this (well, i don't know what it does internally, but it boils down to this):

```
if($i == (int) $s)
```

Which makes the statement true