# Comparing int to string causes weird results in php?

Tags: php, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [comparing two variables returns false result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248465/comparing-two-variables-returns-false-result)

```
<?php
if( "32 is this a bug of php " == 32)
   echo "true";
else
   echo "false";
?>
```

output is :

```
true
```

you can see its output at 
http://codepad.org/hgOisqZ8

why this condition is evaluated as true?

Comment: you can use === (3 equal signs) , so it will also test for equality of the type

Comment: Because "32 is this a bug of php" becomes 32 when converted to int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This is discussed in the [PHP Manual](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).**

> String conversion to numbers
>
> When a string is evaluated in a numeric context, the resulting value
>   and type are determined as follows.
>
> The string will be evaluated as a float if it contains any of the
>   characters '.', 'e', or 'E'. Otherwise, it will be evaluated as an
>   integer.
>
> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used.
>   Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an
>   optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a
>   decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an
>   'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

**Note the part that states**

> If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value
>   used.

Since your string starts with `32` PHP will compare `if(32 == 32)` which will be true.

Use type safe checks, that takes the datatype into consideration, when dealing with types that could be different if this behaviour is not desired. Like

```
1 === 1:   true
1 == 1:    true
1 === "1": false
1 == "1":  true
"foo" === "foo": true
```

Answer (score 7):

because PHP is quite dumb when it comes to type conversion.

This expression is evaluated by first casting "32 is this a bug of php " to integer, which results with 32. Then comparison results in true.

If you want to make type-safe comparison use === operator

```
<?php
if( "32 is this a bug of php " === 32)
   echo "true";
else
   echo "false";
?>
```

Output will be false.

Note that with === operator we've got `"32" !== 32` because one variable is `string` when other is `int`

Comment: I wouldn't call that "dumb", it's just how type casting works in PHP.

Comment: That's why I call it 'quite dumb' not 'totally dumb' ;) IMO all implicit casts from strings are evil, yet I understand that this is by design in PHP

Answer (score 5):

See the documentation for [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

So no, it isn't a bug, it is how the language is designed.

Use `===` if you don't want type juggling.

Answer (score 2):

For attention, also you need to know `$a==$b && $b==$c` **doesn't mean** `$a == $c` in php.

***Example:***

```
var_dump('32E0' == '32');
var_dump('32' == 32);
var_dump(32 == '32 is a bug');
var_dump('32E0' == '32 is a bug');
```

Output is:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Comment: This is since no conversion has to be done when comparing the two strings. So the strings can be handled as strings and not numerical values.

Comment: @inquam "no conversion has to be done when comparing two strings" is **not right** in php, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598407/php-expresses-two-different-strings-to-be-the-same

Comment: For this specific case I meant. But true indeed. PHP can play tricks on our minds ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can also use like this

```
<?php
if( "32 is this a bug of php " == '32')
  echo "true";
else
  echo "false";
?>
```